# Error when starting and registering chaincode_example02

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am following instructions on http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/.

I am using Docker Toolbox on windows and I could start peer and CA successfully. Here is the log when I start peer and CA:

```
[33mvp0_1         |[0m [36m13:18:52.349 [peer] chatWithSomePeers -> DEBU 04c[0m Starting up the first peer of a new network
[33mvp0_1         |[0m 13:18:52.352 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 04d[0m Starting peer with ID=name:"vp0" , network ID=dev, address=172.17.0.3:7051, rootnodes=, validator=true
[33mvp0_1         |[0m [36m13:18:52.358 [consensus/statetransfer] verifyAndRecoverBlockchain -> DEBU 04e[0m Validating existing blockchain, highest validated block is 0, valid through 0
[33mvp0_1         |[0m 13:18:52.359 [consensus/statetransfer] blockThread -> INFO 04f[0m Validated blockchain to the genesis block
[33mvp0_1         |[0m [36m13:18:52.360 [consensus/handler] 1 -> DEBU 050[0m Starting up message thread for consenter
[33mvp0_1         |[0m [36m13:18:52.363 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 051[0m Starting Peer reconnect service (touch service), with period = 6s
[33mvp0_1         |[0m 13:18:52.365 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 052[0m Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
```

But when i start chaincode with below command

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02
```

I get below error:

```
19:30:34.138 [shim] INFO : error with chaincode log level: logger: invalid log level level=
19:30:34.140 [shim] DEBU : Peer address: 0.0.0.0:7052
2016/10/01 19:30:35 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7052: conne
ctex: The requested address is not valid in its context."; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7052" <nil>}
2016/10/01 19:30:36 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7052: conne
ctex: The requested address is not valid in its context."; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7052" <nil>}
19:30:37.143 [shim] ERRO : Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out when dialing
Error starting Simple chaincode: Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out when dialing2016/10/01 19:30:37 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport
failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7052: connectex: The requested address is not valid in its co
ntext."; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7052" <nil>}
```

Why do i get this error?

Comment: could you please try with `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:7051 ` ?

Comment: also can you please try to override logging level using either `CORE_LOGGING_CHAINCODE` or `--logging-level` ? they can be set to one of these values , `CRITICAL | ERROR | WARNING | NOTICE | INFO | DEBUG`

Comment: I have tried multiple ports but none worked. I also tried to check for all listening ports with 'netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"' and used those ports in CORE_PEER_ADDRESS but sadly that also did not work. Is there any other way to communicate with peer?

Comment: could you please show the commands you are using for setting up a peer ?

Comment: I am using the docker-compose as mentioned in http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#running-the-peer-and-ca_1 

The peer gets started as shown in logs in the original question.

Comment: After going through lot of forums and a bit of code in hyperledger-fabric I cam to a conclusion that this issue is related to docket toolbox and might not have anything to do with hyperledger itself. So I am moving to vagrant way now. I still feel that someone knowledgeable on Docker Toolbox should advise on this because most of the first timers on hyperledger are going to use Docker Toolbox instead of vagrant.

Comment: I have also looked into your issue, and learned that it has to do something with windows firewall, and anti virus. The solution is posted here,
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/272
Unfortunately i cannot reproduce it since i am not using docker-toolbox.
Kindly let me know if it helps, so i can post it as answer.

Comment: According to what i understood it has something to do with DockerNAT adapter , so the recommended way was to delete all network adapter and re-install docker toolbox and one more setting in hyper-v virtualization. I realized i dont want to go to this, some other day maybe. Thanks for your kind help. I will keep the question open here , in case anyone lands up here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute those steps:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#starting-and-registering-the-chaincode

You need change CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 to internal IP of dockercompose_vp0_1

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo docker exec -it dockercompose_vp0_1 ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
      inet addr:172.17.0.3  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

Take Ip address of eth0. It's 172.17.0.3

```
osboxes@osboxes:/usr/hyperledger/src/first_test$ CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.3:7051 ./chaincode_example02
08:58:16.619 [shim] INFO : error with chaincode log level: logger: invalid log level level= 
08:58:16.619 [shim] DEBU : Peer address: 172.17.0.3:7051
08:58:16.622 [shim] DEBU : os.Args returns: [./chaincode_example02]
08:58:16.623 [shim] DEBU : Registering.. sending REGISTER
08:58:16.625 [shim] DEBU : []Received message REGISTERED from shim
08:58:16.625 [shim] DEBU : []Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTERED(state:created)
08:58:16.625 [shim] DEBU : Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker by default listens to the address - 192.168.99.100

so, go to the chaincode folder, build the chaincode using- **go build**

-An exe file will be created with name chaincode_example02 .

then run below code-

**CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=192.168.99.100:7051 ./chaincode_example02**